# How may I display only categories from one author?

Tags: wordpress, tags, custom-post-type, categories

I have a site where there are multiple pages for Authors (who each have their own author admin account and ID). in their pages I display their latest submissions (a custom post type).

I would like to show the categories of their submissions on the left, but I'm not sure how to show the categories while having them relate to only that specific author. for example, I'd like it to be displayed as a list:

- Books (2)
- Short stories (12)

That number next to each category would be the number of submissions that specific author has posted. clicking on it would show the submissions in that category.

The categories are pretty static, and are shared across authors, but getting it to relate to only the presently opened authors page is difficult. could anyone help me with this?

This is what I have:

```
<?php

/*
 Plugin Name: Shagun Category Display
 */

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) or die( 'No script kiddies please!' );

define('WP_PLUGIN_URL', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__));
define('SHAGUN_WIDGET_FOLDER', '/shagun-shortcodes/');
define('SHAGUN_WIDGET_URL', WP_PLUGIN_URL . '/shagun-shortcodes');


function Category_display($atts) {

    ob_start();    
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'author' => ''
    ), $atts ));


    $args = array(
        'post_type' =>  'case_study'
    );

    $categories = get_categories($args);

    echo '<ul>';

    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $url = get_term_link($category);
        ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $url;?>"><?php echo $category->name; ?></a></li>

        <?php
    }

    echo '<li> end of list </li></ul>';


    wp_reset_postdata();
    return ob_get_clean();   
};


add_shortcode('Category_display', 'Category_display');
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you'll have to make a query for each category to check how many posts the author has made for that category.

```
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $url = get_term_link($category);

    $args = [
        'cat' => $category->term_id,
        'author' => $atts['author'],
        'post_type' => 'case_study',
    ];
    $q = new WP_Query($args);
    ?>

    <li><a href="<?php echo $url;?>"><?php echo $category->name; ?> (<?php echo $q->found_posts; ?>)</a></li>

    <?php
}
```

If you want to only display the categories the author has posted stuff in, you can easily do that too, by adding this line under `$q = [...]`:

```
if ($q->found_posts < 1) continue;
```

*This is untested, so there might be some typos.*